# binding with object

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I want to bind projectName Property which is in the project object...here is my view.xaml.cs file..

**Code Behind:**

```
        TempData t = new TempData();
        t.Contract = contract;
        t.Project = project;
        this.DataContext = t;
```

And I'm binding this in textblock like this but its not working.

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectName,  Mode=TwoWay}" 
           DataContext="{Binding t}" FontSize="20" 
           Foreground="Black" 
           TextAlignment="Right" 
           Margin="100,0,0,0">
     enter code here
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Could you post your TempData class definition ? Is ProjectName a dependency property ?

Comment: "<enter code here/TextBlock>" is a copy and paste mistake? or is that in the code you want to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do binding at that time the property name and binding path must have same with character case. Here I am posting code for what you want

XAML
Don't DataContext at both side. Use either in XAML or in code-behind

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
           FontSize="20" 
           Foreground="Black" 
           TextAlignment="Right" 
           Margin="100,0,0,0" />
```

C#

```
class TempData
{
    public string Contract { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}

public sealed partial class BlankPage2 : Page
{
    public BlankPage2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        string contract = "contract", project = "project";
        TempData t = new TempData();
        t.Contract = contract;
        t.ProjectName = project;
        this.DataContext = t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to say is this (but it's hard to say)...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Project.ProjectName,  Mode=TwoWay}" 
       FontSize="20" 
       Foreground="Black" 
       TextAlignment="Right" 
       Margin="100,0,0,0">
    ...
</TextBlock>
```

Or if you'd like...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectName,  Mode=TwoWay}" 
       DataContext="{Binding Project}" FontSize="20" 
       Foreground="Black" 
       TextAlignment="Right" 
       Margin="100,0,0,0">
    ...
</TextBlock>
```

providing that your `TempData.Project` is some project class with `ProjectName`

```
// in your code-behind...
this.DataContext = new TempData
{
    Contract = new Contrac{},
    Project = new Project{ ProjectName = "My proj...", }
}
// this is for the window or user-control (I guess) - thus DataContext to start with...
```

Your TextBox DataContext is the same (TempData) - **there is no `t` there**.

**That's where you are already** - i.e. the 'context' of your TextBox (unless you have some other controls in between, list items etc.). Just bind directly to `Project.ProjectName`